# Why is PAM broken after installing nis?

Tags: debian, pam, ldap, kerberos, nis

I'm a Software Engineer with some system admin experience currently trying to setup some Linux infrastructure at a new workplace which previously only had Windows infrastucture. For Political reasons I can't simply integrate with the current Active Directory setup and have to start from scratch. I am using Debian.

I'm currently trying to setup kerbos, ldap, nfs and nis. I believe I've set up the server correctly and that everything is working there as I've tested logging in with kerberos and the nis client has been talking to the server also I can mount the NFS drives.

Since installing nis on the client I am no longer able to login not even with the root account unless I launch in recovery mode.

I have been trying to fix this for a day and a half and I'm out of ideas.

Here is what I think the issue is as pam is outputting to `/var/log/auth.log`

```
lightdm: PAM (other) illegal module type: passwd:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
lightdm: PAM (other) illegal module type: group:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
lightdm: PAM (other) illegal module type: shadow:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
lightdm: PAM (other) illegal module type: gshadow:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...files]
lightdm: PAM (other) no module name supplied
lightdm: PAM (other) illegal module type: hosts:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...files]
lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
systemd-logind[667]: New session c1 of user lightdm.
systemd: PAM (other) illegal module type: passwd:
systemd: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
systemd: PAM (other) illegal module type: group:
systemd: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
systemd: PAM (other) illegal module type: shadow:
systemd: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
systemd: PAM (other) illegal module type: gshadow:
systemd: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...files]
systemd: PAM (other) no module name supplied
systemd: PAM (other) illegal module type: hosts:
systemd: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...files]
systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
lightdm: PAM (lightdm) illegal module type: passwd:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
lightdm: PAM (lightdm) illegal module type: group:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
lightdm: PAM (lightdm) illegal module type: shadow:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
lightdm: PAM (lightdm) illegal module type: gshadow:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...files]
lightdm: PAM (lightdm) no module name supplied
lightdm: PAM (lightdm) illegal module type: hosts:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...files]
lightdm: PAM (other) illegal module type: passwd:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
lightdm: PAM (other) illegal module type: group:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
lightdm: PAM (other) illegal module type: shadow:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
lightdm: PAM (other) illegal module type: gshadow:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...files]
lightdm: PAM (other) no module name supplied
lightdm: PAM (other) illegal module type: hosts:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...files]
lightdm: PAM (lightdm) illegal module type: passwd:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
lightdm: PAM (lightdm) illegal module type: group:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
lightdm: PAM (lightdm) illegal module type: shadow:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
lightdm: PAM (lightdm) illegal module type: gshadow:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...files]
lightdm: PAM (lightdm) no module name supplied
lightdm: PAM (lightdm) illegal module type: hosts:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...files]
lightdm: PAM (other) illegal module type: passwd:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
lightdm: PAM (other) illegal module type: group:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
lightdm: PAM (other) illegal module type: shadow:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
lightdm: PAM (other) illegal module type: gshadow:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...files]
lightdm: PAM (other) no module name supplied
lightdm: PAM (other) illegal module type: hosts:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...files]
lightdm: pam_krb5(lightdm:auth): user billy authenticated as billy@PROPACK
lightdm: PAM (lightdm) illegal module type: passwd:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
lightdm: PAM (lightdm) illegal module type: group:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
lightdm: PAM (lightdm) illegal module type: shadow:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
lightdm: PAM (lightdm) illegal module type: gshadow:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...files]
lightdm: PAM (lightdm) no module name supplied
lightdm: PAM (lightdm) illegal module type: hosts:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...files]
lightdm: PAM (other) illegal module type: passwd:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
lightdm: PAM (other) illegal module type: group:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
lightdm: PAM (other) illegal module type: shadow:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...compat]
lightdm: PAM (other) illegal module type: gshadow:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...files]
lightdm: PAM (other) no module name supplied
lightdm: PAM (other) illegal module type: hosts:
lightdm: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...files]
```

I'm not quite sure why this is. It all started after installing the nis package on the client however I don't think nis is the issue as it is talking to the server fine judging by the output from `systemctl status nis`

```
systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start NIS client and server daemons....
nis[1348]: Setting NIS domainname to: domain.
nis[1348]: Starting NIS services: ypbind.
systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start NIS client and server daemons..
```

I also uninstalled nis (Since installing nis was when this started), rebooted and the problem still exists.

I've checked the dependencies for nis and I can't see why any of them would have caused this to happen. I believe that pam is parsing my `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file which you can see below if needed.

```
passwd:         compat files systemd nis
group:          compat files systemd nis
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Please let me know if there is any other information you need to help debug this issue.

Edit:

`/etc/pam.d/other` contents:

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/other - specify the PAM fallback behaviour
#
# Note that this file is used for any unspecified service; for example
#if /etc/pam.d/cron  specifies no session modules but cron calls
#pam_open_session, the session module out of /etc/pam.d/other is
#used.  If you really want nothing to happen then use pam_permit.so or
#pam_deny.so as appropriate.

# We fall back to the system default in /etc/pam.d/common-*
# 

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-password
@include common-session
```

`/etc/pam.d/lightdm` contents:

```
#%PAM-1.0

# Block login if they are globally disabled
auth      requisite pam_nologin.so

# Load environment from /etc/environment and ~/.pam_environment
session      required pam_env.so readenv=1
session      required pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale

@include common-auth

-auth  optional pam_gnome_keyring.so

@include common-account

# SELinux needs to be the first session rule. This ensures that any
# lingering context has been cleared. Without out this it is possible
# that a module could execute code in the wrong domain.
# When the module is present, "required" would be sufficient (When SELinux
# is disabled, this returns success.)
session  [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so close

session  required        pam_limits.so
session  required        pam_loginuid.so
@include common-session

# SELinux needs to intervene at login time to ensure that the process
# starts in the proper default security context. Only sessions which are
# intended to run in the user's context should be run after this.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so open
# When the module is present, "required" would be sufficient (When SELinux
# is disabled, this returns success.)

-session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start

@include common-password
```

`/etc/pam.d/common-session` As requested

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-session - session-related modules common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of modules that define tasks to be performed
# at the start and end of sessions of *any* kind (both interactive and
# non-interactive).
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
session [default=1]         pam_permit.so
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
session requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
session required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
session optional            pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000
session required    pam_unix.so 
session optional            pam_sss.so 
session optional            pam_ldap.so 
session optional    pam_systemd.so 
# end of pam-auth-update config

passwd:         compat systemd nis
group:          compat systemd nis
shadow:         compat nis
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns nis
```

**Update**
I have switched to sssd as suggested by @Michael Ströder however this has not changed anything.

Comment: Does `file /etc/nsswitch.conf` return `ASCII text` (good) or `ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators` (bad)?

Comment: Does the file `/etc/pam.d/other` exist, and if so, what does it contain? Same question for `/etc/pam.d/lightdm`?

Comment: @roaima Thanks for your input I checked for CRLF with `dos2unix < /etc/nsswitch.conf | cmp - /etc/nsswitch.conf` and the files are the same so it appears to have correct line endings. I've also added the config of those files to my question.

Comment: Is there any PAM file containing `passwd`. Just checking for ooops moments :-)

Comment: I used `grep -ri passwd` in `/etc/pam.d` the only instance I found regarding passwd was `common-session:passwd:         compat systemd nis` most of the files should be default the only one I've edited was `/etc/nssswitch.conf`

Comment: Can you please include `common-session` in your question. It should not have a line starting `passwd:` in it - this may be the cause of the error

Comment: Added as requested. I have also moved from using NIS to sssd as the answer suggested however I've not noticed anything different and the auth.log is still throwing the same errors. I think you're probably right about pam being configured wrong.

Comment: Glad to see someone's jumped in and answered you. Indeed, the trailing lines in `common-session` would have been the cause of the issue

Comment: Big thanks to you for leading me in the right direction. No idea how they got there I've tried not to edit the pam files as I don't really have  a clue what I'm doing with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of your `/etc/pam.d/common-session`, there seems to be a (partial?) copy of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
# end of pam-auth-update config

passwd:         compat systemd nis  <--
group:          compat systemd nis  <-- These lines definitely
shadow:         compat nis          <-- don't belong here!
gshadow:        files               <--
                                    <--
hosts:          files dns nis       <--
```

This could be a simple copy/paste accident, or maybe an error in a document you've been following.

`pam-auth-update`, Debian's tool for updating PAM configuration as packages are installed/removed uses templates located in `/usr/share/pam-configs`, but since the wrong lines are located after the `# end of pam-auth-update config` comment line, my bet would be on a manual editing error.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the answer you expected: Do not use NIS!

Seriously, NIS is a security night-mare. The security folks in your company will blame you for setting up a new NIS installation today.

Since you already have an LDAP server in place use solely this to deliver NSS map data to the Linux boxes. You need client software to provide local PAM and NSS integration based on your LDAP server's data.

There are two generic NSS/PAM client demons both with decent documentation:

- [sssd](https://sssd.io)
- [nss-pam-ldapd](https://arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd/)

Comment: I appreciate the advice, however I have switched to using sssd and it hasn't fixed my issue.